# How to update the sdb server?

Tags: tizen-wearable-sdk

**Background**: I've just installed a new version of the Tizen Studio. 
I've installed the Wearable 2.3.2 component in the setup wizard because this is the closest to the Tizen 2.3.2.1 displayed by my Gear S2 in its Device Info. I want to deploy a watchface.

**Problem**: When I run `sdb connect` I get the following warning (six times!):

```
The version of SDB client (2.3.0) is not same with that of SDB server (2.2.83).
  It may cause version compatibility problems.
  It is recommended to use SDB server with version 2.3.0. *
```

However, I get the `connected to 192.168.1.4:26101` message at the end.

How to update the "SDB server"? Or can I just ignore the warning?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record. **It seems that the warning can be simply ignored**. I could successfully deploy the application on the watch without any problem. I leave this here, maybe it will be useful for somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Ubuntu:

Terminal commands:

```
whereis sdb
```

Some sdb locations will be shown.
Delete all the locations.

```
sudo rm -rf /path/
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your PATH that which sdb it's using, if you connect the device through IDE in a newer version, and PATH pointing to an older version sdb, this warning occurs, once you update the PATH to the latest this warning should be gone.